# Ubuntu 16.04 applications freeze randomly, mouse and system shortly after

Tags: 16.04, laptop, acer

I have an Acer Travelmate X349 with dual boot Win 10/Ubuntu 16.04. Sometimes in Ubuntu all applications randomly freeze but I am able to move the cursor for a few moments. After ~5 seconds the mouse also stops responding and I have to do a hard reboot. I have run a memory test (memtest86) which completed without errors. The SSD is also fine according to Ubuntu's Disks application.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: When this happens, does switching to another TTY work? Try pressing 'Ctrl+Alt+F1', you can do the same when it's not frozen to see what I mean, 'Ctrl+Alt+F7' to get back. If the laptop has a  small light that represents if numlock is on, does pressing the numlock button turn on/off the light?

Comment: The system doesn't respond to Ctrl+Alt+F1 either, it's totally locked. No lights for caps lock/numlock.

Comment: Alright, does it respond to the magic sysrq key?  Hold alt+sysrq (normally same key as printscreen) and hit the following keys: 'REISUB'. This will reboot the computer http://blog.kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/

Comment: @Tobias Computer hasn't frozen since yesterday after I updated the kernel from 4.4 to 4.8 so I haven't been able to test it, hopefully the problem is gone now

Comment: If you feel confident that the problem is gone, please post the solution as an answer so other people can see it as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the kernel from 4.4 to 4.8 seems to have fixed the problem. 3 days without crashes now.